# Android vitals - Stuck Wake Locks and foreground service

Tags: android, google-play-console

In Developer console - Android vitals I see warning that app has "Stuck partial wake locks".
In [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock.html) it's described as

> A partial wake lock becomes stuck if it is held for a long time while your app is running in the background (no part of your app is visible to the user).

It's true that app is running in background (playing audio) but I use foreground service and whole time when app holds lock notification is visible.

Later in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock.html) you can read

> Make sure some portion of your app remains in the foreground. For example, if you need to run a service, start a foreground service instead. This visually indicates to the user that your app is still running.

But it doesn't seems to be true. Is Android vitals ignoring that app has foreground service? Does anyone has similar experience?

EDIT: here is code from my AudioService

```
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = null;
boolean mHasWakeLock;

void acquireLocks(){

    if (!mHasWakeLock) {
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,TAG);
        mWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        mHasWakeLock = true;
    }
}

void releaseLocks() {
    if (mWakeLock != null) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        mWakeLock = null;
    }
    mHasWakeLock = false;
}

void play(){
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    acquireLocks();
}

void stop(){
    releaseLocks();
    stopForeground(true);
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code for the wakelock and foreground service

Comment: Same problem. App needs partial wake lock and user need it too. But Google thinks otherwise... If you find a solution pls share it (I'm not use setReferenceCounted) Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have a similar one.

Answer (score 4):

I think, the problem is in

```
mWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
```

Should be `true`, so the System can count, when you release the lock.
In your case, you may well be releasing it, but the System does not "see" it.
This might confuse vitals.

Try it with that flag set to true.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think setReferenceCounted false is safer. It means that it's enought to call release once and it doesn't matter how many times you called acquire. But in this case I use flag to check whether I have lock or not. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#setReferenceCounted(boolean)

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have a similar one.